# How to implement a WYSIWYG editor for WebApp in Business Catalyst

Tags: web-applications, wysiwyg, business-catalyst

I have created my own WebApp in Business Catalyst and I want to implement a WYSIWYG editor for the multi line string custom fields.

Can I use the one that BC uses themselves in the WebApp admin interface?

I see they use radeditor and I wonder if I can implement this in my own WebApp interface?

I have worked around this by implementing my own tinyMCE function but the one thing I am missing is the ability to insert pictures via a dialog box file selector. I see there is a paid-plugin to tinyMCE to implement a file selector but I am not sure if this would work with Business Catalyst, or if I would then need to also implement an ASP connector along with it to find the files (which I assume we would not have access to do).

Can we use BC's WYSIWYG implementation in our own WebApp intefaces?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Not really.

In the backend you can only use the BC WYSIWYG editor.

On the frontend (web app input form) you can use the tinyMCE function as you mentioned but it doesn't allow for image insertion, only styling and formatting. You can create a custom field for an image and then code that to appear somewhere in the code but it isn't possible for the user to control where the image is inserted.

Comment: I am not wanting this on the frontend. I am talking about the backend. I have created my own BC App using the BC Open Platform and I have my own edit form with textarea elements which I want to control via a WYSIWYG editor. I have it all working on the backend via tinyMCE except for the image insertion so i was hoping I could hook into the WYSIWYG tool which BC themselves use which you would think would then allow the image insertion.

Comment: @David - Ah okay. Web Apps and BC Apps are two different things sections (though they can be used together). It can be confusing. With that said, I don't know of anyway. Try asking on the [BC Developer Forum](https://forums.adobe.com/community/business_catalyst/developer_forum), they have people with more experience than me.